# Tensorflow Session management issue | When session managed by other TF module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am  using an external module for tensorflow work, getting session management issue when try to use it in flask application from pickle file, can someone please help me

> ValueError: Tensor("TensorSliceDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant)
>   must be from the same graph as Tensor("Iterator:0", shape=(),
>   dtype=resource).

Sample code structure

```
from io import StringIO
import flask
import pandas as pd
import tensorrec as tr
import tensorflow as tf


class ScoringService(object):
    model = None                
    model_path = 'path for pickle file'
    @classmethod
    def get_model(cls):
        if cls.model == None:
            cls.model = tr.TensorRec.load_model(model_path)

        return cls.model

    @classmethod
    def get_reco(cls, model,use_ft, ite_ft):
            tf.reset_default_graph()
            predictions = model.predict(use_ft, ite_ft)
        return predictions

    @classmethod
    def predict(cls, input):
        clf = cls.get_model()
        n_reco_test = cls.get_reco(clf, input,use_ft, ite_ft)
        return n_reco_test

# The flask app for serving predictions
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def transformation():
    data = None

    # Convert from CSV to pandas
    if flask.request.content_type == 'text/csv':
        data = flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')
        s = StringIO(data)
        data = pd.read_csv(s, header=None)
    else:
        return flask.Response(response='This predictor only supports CSV data', status=415, mimetype='text/plain')
    # Do the prediction
    predictions = ScoringService.predict(data)
    return flask.Response(response=predictions, status=200,mimetype='text/csv')
```

more detail about error

```
"POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "AHC/2.0"
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 350, in _apply_op_helper
g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5637, in _get_graph_from_inputs
_assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5573, in _assert_same_graph
original_item)
```

Comment: try removing `tf.reset_default_graph()` ?

Comment: yes, removed but still not working

Comment: what is use_ft and ite_ft ? and how did you provide it in the predict method ?

Comment: use_ft and ite-ft are user feature and item feature, both are loaded from pickle file from input data and provide to do predication

Comment: but in the predict method how do you pass them ? in the get_reco fn ?

Comment: inside predict method, I have a function to load the dependencies which load the data from pickle and pass to get reco

Comment: `def predict(cls, input):
        clf = cls.get_model()
        n_reco_test = cls.get_reco(clf, input,use_ft, ite_ft)
        return n_reco_test`   

my doubt is how did you pass user_ft and ite_ft in get_reco here ?
you didnt return it from the get_model nor these are initialised elsewhere.

Comment: yes, I load both in between and these both object have values